# Check if container element for processing instruction exists

Tags: xml, xslt, processing-instruction

I was handling this processing instruction: `<?Pub _kern Amount="-25pt"?>`

with:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('Pub')">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with(., '_kern')">
                <xsl:attribute name="style"><xsl:text>padding-left: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="if (contains(.,'Amount')) then (substring-before(substring-after(., 'Amount=&quot;'), '&quot;')) else '12pt'"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

but this only works when the PI is inside a container element like `<div>`, etc. I received an error because the XSLT was trying to add a style tag to a non-existent parent element. If I include a `<span>` before the `<xsl:attribute name="style">` then the code doesn't work when the PI is inside a container element. How can I detect whether there is a container element so I know whether or not to add a span? Unless there is a better way to do this, I'm a beginner with XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the processing instruction has a parent element by adding a simple condition

```
 <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('Pub')[parent::*]">
```

Be wary though, if your XML looks like this:

```
<div>
   <?Pub _kern Amount="-25pt"?>    
</div>
```

You may still get an error if the whitespace text node has been matched and copied first. You may need to include the `xsl:strip-space` command in your XSLT.

For example, this gets an error

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('Pub')[parent::*]">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(., '_kern')">
                    <xsl:attribute name="style"><xsl:text>padding-left: </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="if (contains(.,'Amount')) then (substring-before(substring-after(., 'Amount=&quot;'), '&quot;')) else '12pt'"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this doesn't....

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('Pub')[parent::*]">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="starts-with(., '_kern')">
                    <xsl:attribute name="style"><xsl:text>padding-left: </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="if (contains(.,'Amount')) then (substring-before(substring-after(., 'Amount=&quot;'), '&quot;')) else '12pt'"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT: In response to your comments, even with `xsl:strip-space` you still get an error if there was a preceding-sibling before the processing instruction

```
<div>
    <text></text>
    <?Pub _kern Amount="-25pt"?>    
</div>
```

This is because you cannot add an attribute to a parent element if that parent has already had child nodes output.

If the intention is to try to add the attribute to the parent where you can, but if not create a span tag instead, then you could change the format of the template matching the processing instruction to this:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('Pub')">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(parent::*) or preceding-sibling::node()">
            <span>
                <!-- Add attribute -->
            </span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- Add attribute -->
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

And the adding of the attribute can be done in a template to avoid repetition of coding. Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="processing-instruction('Pub')">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(parent::*) or preceding-sibling::node()">
                <span>
                    <xsl:call-template name="processing-instruction"/>
                </span>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="processing-instruction"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="processing-instruction">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="starts-with(., '_kern')">
                <xsl:attribute name="style"><xsl:text>padding-left: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="if (contains(.,'Amount')) then (substring-before(substring-after(., 'Amount=&quot;'), '&quot;')) else '12pt'"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Tim C, but I'm still getting this error without the span: "An attribute node (style) cannot be created after the children of the containing element." I did have `<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />` at the top of the stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks @Tim C, this worked for me. I appreciate you taking the time to correct my errors. I had other processing instructions as well which I omitted for relevance but I added them to the processing-instruction template.

Answer (score 0):

This worked, which I would not have gotten without @Tim C's help:

```
<xsl:template match="processing-instruction('Pub')">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with(., '_kern') and processing-instruction()[parent::*]">
            <xsl:attribute name="style"><xsl:text>padding-left: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="if (contains(.,'Amount')) then (substring-before(substring-after(., 'Amount=&quot;'), '&quot;')) else '12pt'"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="starts-with(., '_kern')">
            <span><xsl:attribute name="style"><xsl:text>padding-left: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="if (contains(.,'Amount')) then (substring-before(substring-after(., 'Amount=&quot;'), '&quot;')) else '12pt'"/>
            </xsl:attribute></span>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise/>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

It's probably not exactly right but it got the job done.

Comment: I think your first `xsl:when` statement will always return false, because where you do `processing-instruction()[parent::*]">`, this is looking for a second processing instruction that is a child of the current processing instruction, which is not possible! You could change it to `<xsl:when test="starts-with(., '_kern') and parent::*">` but then you might get the error. Perhaps it would be easiest to just output the new `span` in all cases?

Comment: I am leaving this here as an example of what not to do, I used @Tim C's edited solution above.